Tips on how to end a story properly
I enjoy writing short stories, but I always struggle with how to write the ending. Do you have any tips for me?

Which of your short stories seemed to you to have ended properly and which not, and why?

In most stories, long or short, the ending is related to the beginning.
Act I: In the beginning, the reader is introduced to the protagonist in the protagonists' normal world. In this normal world, we (the author) have the protagonist deal with some normal problems or interactions so the readers get to know the type of person the protagonist is.
Then something happens that is not normal for the protagonist. Somebody new to interact with, or something new and out of the ordinary happens, and the protagonist cannot just ignore it. [writers call this the "inciting incident".]
Act II: Our protagonist reacts; they cannot just ignore this thing. But the "out of the ordinary" gets worse or more extreme. The protagonist continues to react, trying to solve the problem of this new thing, to deal with it.
In most stories, after a few failures, the protagonist succeeds.
Act III: The protagonist is finally victorious, we show them, after their failures, conquer whatever threat they faced, and often whatever weakness they had that was holding them back.
Finale: And in the conclusion of the story, we either show the protagonist returning to their normal world we introduced at the beginning -- now things go  back to normal -- or we show the protagonist in their "new normal".
Meaning, their circumstances have changed irrevocably, but they were victorious in overcoming the threat, and now have overcome a weakness in themselves, or learned something new, or improved somehow.
There are of course endless twists on this that have been successful, but most successful stories follow this three act structure because it is what people enjoy reading.
Readers enjoy seeing a hero gain victory, but the victory is meaningless if the hero did not suffer to win it -- the more painful, heartbreaking, frustrating and difficult the challenge, the more heroic the hero becomes.
Even in a short story.
I suspect, if you have difficulty ending a story, the problem lies in the middle, in Act II, or even in Act I -- you failed to introduce a big problem.
Once the hero defeats the villain (which might not be person) the ending is usually obvious -- the hero is victorious, so we transition from the "unusual" circumstances of battling a problem into "problem dealt with", and a brief illustration of the "New Normal".
If the end is hard to write, it may be because the story before it doesn't really support an ending. You need to prove a change in the hero; show that overcoming the challenge has made her stronger, or smarter, or she learned something useful.
Endings are satisfying because we (the readers) come away with this change, it speaks to our psychology. We want our hardships to mean something more than just loss and pain. We want our hardships to be worth it in some sense.
One of the most difficult things for beginning writers to learn is they have to beat up their heroes. Simple wish fulfillment stories are for little children.
Adults want their heroes to earn their endings, to make mistakes (like we all do) and suffer consequences (like we all do) but not give up, not surrender, and not just win in the end without paying the price.
Even in a short story, although all of these Acts are compressed to one or two incidents. If the hero earns her ending, then the ending is usually obvious -- she either gets back to her normal world, or if that is not possible, she takes her place in the new normal world.
We show her briefly, happy or content in that circumstance.

Different stories have different endings. Some possible endings are:

Surprise the reader by an unexpected turn of events.
Provide the answer to a question posed at the beginning.
Complete the protagonist's journey of personal development and show how they finally overcome their inner obstacles.
Conclude a series of events and show what results they have.
Let the protagonist achieve his or her goal or show how and why they fail.
Provide an explanation for a mystery.
Do not provide a resolution and leave the main question unanswered.

Of course, for your story to be able to have one of these or any other ending, that ending has to be set up by how you began your story:

For the reader to be surprised by an unexpected turn of events, you have to build a certain expectation in your readers that you can then subvert.
To provide an answer you must first pose a question.
For your protagonist to be able to complete his or her journey of personal development, the story must provide both an occasion and an oportunity to change.
For events to have a conclusion, they must have an aim.
And so on...

In turn every beginning usually has a natural ending. So if you don't know your story's ending, look at the beginning and try to understand how you can complement and complete it.
